# HTML style input with Cakephp Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, button, formhelper

In my index.ctp, I am creating a table and the last column of the table will have 3 buttons to perform actions on that specific row.  The buttons will be View, Edit, and Delete.

I am trying to decide what will be easier, using cakephp's form helper to create a button and link the button with the corressponding controller action, or use javascript to create the input but then how would I link the onclick to the controller action.

I am a total noob at cakephp so any help would be great.

Here is the code for the buttons using the form:

```
<td><input type="button" id="viewButton" value="View"/><input type="button" id="editButton" value="Edit"/><input type="button" id="deleteButton" value="Delete"/></td>
```

(I don't have any events on the button becase I don't know how to link the events to the controller)

Here is the same thing but written with cakephp's form helper:

```
<td><?php echo $this->Form->button('View', array('type' => 'button', 'action' => 'view'), $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id']);
echo $this->Form->button('Edit', array('type' => 'button', 'action' => 'edit', $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id']));
echo $this->Form->button('Delete', array('type' => 'button', 'action' => 'delete', $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id']));?>
</td>
```

I needed help with getting the buttons to communicate with their actions.
Ultimately I will try and open a modal window with one of the views in the window.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question.

I can use a button like this

```
<button onclick="location.href='<?php echo $html->url('/controller/ 
action'); ?>';">Click me</button>
```

When adjusted to fit my specific program I got

```
<td> <input type="button" class="viewButton" value="View" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'localClocks', 'action' => 'view', $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id'])); ?>';"/>
    <input type="button" class="editButton" value="Edit" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'localClocks', 'action' => 'edit', $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id'])); ?>';"/>
```

Html->url(array('controller' => 'localClocks', 'action' => 'delete', $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id'])); ?>';"/>

I just thought I would share what I found.
Thanks

Comment: +1 for the follow up and sharing your solution instead of abandoning the question.